# MySQL match a value with wildcard in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `teachers` table that looks like this:

| teacherid | teacherfname | teacherlname | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alexander | Bennett | 55.30 |

I would like to return any record that contains a given string in the `teacherfname`, `teacherlname` and `salary` columns.

What I have right now (this returns exact match only):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE 'Alexander' IN (teacherfname, teacherlname, salary)
```

What I would like to do is something like this (this would not return anything):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE '%Alex%' IN (teacherfname, teacherlname, salary)
```

What do I need to make the query work? Thank you.

Comment: You either try to implement a full text search, which is already [implemented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html), or need to repeat `... or columnN like :your_wildcard_variable or columnN+1 like ...`. SQL table is not a text file, so by default such operation is not common for relational structures. Please, describe, what task you try to solve with such code.

Comment: Alternatively you may add a view/calculated column with `concat(col1, ' ', col2, ' ', colN)` and perform search on this column with general `like`. But it will fail for some special cases (where the search string contains separator inside)

Comment: Thanks! the table may not be altered for indexing but the alternative way could work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the value `%Alex%` won't ever match the salary column. If you want to search for any rows where the first name or last name include "Alex" I would use simple pattern matching, and force all comparisons to use the same letter case.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `teachers`
WHERE lower(teacherfname) like '%alex%' 
   or lower(teacherlname) like '%alex%'
```

Comment: @PhilCoulson You learn something new every day. The MySQL manual reads: `In MySQL, SQL patterns are case-insensitive by default.`

Comment: Thanks! This is simpler than I thought. It needs to match salary as well but I can just add one more condition the the WHERE clause.